# how to create a library with Protobuf elements without dependencies

Tags: c++, g++, protocol-buffers

I have to create a Library for my work that contains Protobuf elements. It should run on every other PC without installing Protobuf. But I can not make the library run without having also the Protobuf files in the same folder (so I compile this files to and the user have to install Protobuf)

So I created for this a test program to demonstrate my problem:

->alias.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

package aliasPackage;

message NumberSave{
    int32 number = 1;
}
```

I created the .h and .cc with

```
protoc -I. --cpp_out=. alias.proto
```

->Backbone.h

```
#include "alias.pb.h"

class Backbone{
    public:
        Backbone();
        ~Backbone();
        void save_Number(int value);
        int get_Number();
    private:
        aliasPackage::NumberSave number;
};
```

->Backbone.cpp

```
#include "../header/Backbone.h"
#include <google/protobuf/stubs/common.h>


Backbone::Backbone()
{
    number.set_number(0);
}

Backbone::~Backbone()
{
    google::protobuf::ShutdownProtobufLibrary();
}

void Backbone::save_Number(int value)
{
    number.set_number(value);
}

int Backbone::get_Number()
{
    return number.number();
}
```

->Backbone.h for the lib

```
class Backbone{
    public:
        Backbone();
        ~Backbone();
        void save_Number(int value);
        int get_Number();
};
```

Creating the lib out of the files with this command (I thought about a static one, compiling the all independences into the file, but it seems not to work)

```
g++ -c --std=c++20 -O3 -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -I/usr/local/include *.c* -lpthread -L/usr/local/lib -lprotobuf && ar rcs Backbone.sll *.o
```

->main.cpp

```
#include "../libs/lib/Backbone.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    auto backbone = new Backbone();
    backbone->save_Number(5);
    std::cout<<backbone->get_Number()<<std::endl;
    delete backbone;
    return 0;
}
```

Compile command

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic --std=c++20 -O3 main.cpp -L. -l:../libs/lib/Backbone.sll
```

What am I doing wrong? What's the right command to create a Lib so that users can use it without installing Protobuf?

Comment: Static libs are just bundles of object files.  If a static lib depends on another lib then you need both.  Also you can't re-define `Backbone` like that.  You probably need something like the pimpl pattern if you want to prevent users from needing protobuf headers.  They'll still need the object files to link to though.

Comment: @MilesBudnek so there is no way to generate a library that can be used by a another Person without installing all librarys I have installed ?